# Best combo for three given dice (even and odd)

Tags: probability

So this is just a thought experiment while I was playing around with three dice.  So basically a player has to choose a combination of even/odd based on what he thinks the three dice will roll. By the way, I'm assuming six-sided dice.

The question is what is the best combo for highest rate of success at predicting?

Example:
Player says "even-odd-odd"
Each die is rolled **separately**

Comment: As the probability of rolling an even and odd number is the same, all permutations will have the same success rate.

Comment: Pretty sure no matter what you call, you will have a $1/8$ chance of getting it.

Comment: This is similar to asking to make a prediction on exactly what numbers will appear on the three die. Of'course, every permutation of 3 will have the same probability.

Answer (score 0):

Because the chances of getting odd or even are both $1/2$, no matter what three parities you choose, you will always get a probability of $1/8$ (you can replace "parity" with odd or even, doesn't matter):$$P(\text{parity})\cdot P(\text{parity})\cdot P(\text{parity}) = \frac12\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac12=\frac18$$